# How to generate an infinite list of fibonacci numbers using curried function in SMLNJ?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have coded up a general purpose routine that takes multiple arguments and generates an infinite list of fibonacci numbers which is as follows:

```
datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq) ;
fun fibo (a,b) = Cons(a, fn () => fibo(b,a+b));

val fib = fibo(0 , 1);
```

But the problem is I want to use currying technique to generate this infinite list of fibonacci numbers starting from 0 and 1, I am totally perplexed about the concept of currying.

Can some enlighten me about the concept of currying by using this example? How do I use currying to generate an infinite list of fibonacci numbers in SMLNJ?

Comment: you should not try to erase questions and answers on SO. If an answer is valid check the green arrow, it will be really better.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq) ;
fun fibo a b = Cons(a, fn () => fibo b (a + b));

val fib = fibo 0 1;
```

And another (very useful) curried function:

```
(* take n seq returns the first n items in seq. Raises Subscript if there
   are too few items. *)
fun take 0 _            = []
  | take _ Nil          = raise Subscript
  | take n (Cons (a,f)) = a :: take (n - 1) (f ())
```

Example (in the mosml interpreter, so it might look slightly different from SML/NJ):

```
- take 10 fib;
> val it = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34] : int list
```

And just to show off a little of the power of currying:

```
val firstTen = take 10

- firstTen fib;
> val it = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34] : int list
```

What happens here, is that I only give `take` one argument. `take` has type `int -> 'a seq -> 'a list`, so by giving it the `int` argument, I get something of type `'a seq -> 'a list` - namely, a function that returns 10 items of the `'a seq` you give it as input.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is a little wrong as it mixes curried and uncurried forms of `fibo`.

If I understand correctly, there's not much to enlighten you about at the level of coding. There's a tiny syntactic difference between the curried and uncurried definitions.

```
- fun plus_uncurried (a, b) = a + b;
val plus_uncurried = fn : int * int -> int
- plus_uncurried (3,5);
val it = 8 : int
-  fun plus_curried a b = a + b;
val plus_curried = fn : int -> int -> int
- plus_curried 3 5;
val it = 8 : int
- val incr = plus_curried 1;
val incr = fn : int -> int
- incr 4;
val it = 5 : int
```

At the conceptual level, curried functions seem a little trickier, at least at first. I personally just think of a curried function as one that returns a function that wants more arguments. When you finally give the last argument you get your answer.

(I'm not sure why you tagged this question with OCaml, but in OCaml currying is the idiomatic form for functions. So you get used to it right away.)

It may be you're looking for something more complicated than a function of type `int -> int -> int seq`. If so, you'll need to describe a little more carefully what you're looking for. Just specifying the type of what you're looking for would probably help a lot.

**Update**

There's nothing more complicated in `fibo` than in the examples above, other than that you have a recursive call. If you just change the first part of `fibo` in the same way that `plus_uncurried` changes into `plus_curried`, you will have handled the definition part. To handle the calling part, change your recursive call in the same way that calls to `plus_uncurried` are changed into calls to `plus_curried`.

Comment: oops i just copied the wrong code i was trying the currying myself I know that part and I understand the concepts of currying as well its just that in this tricky infinite Fibonacci sequence code I am unable to apply that logic ....Thanks for pointing it out to avoid further misconceptions... I will correct it .... what I am specifically looking for is how do I write the same function of infinite Fibonacci list as above using the curry functions...everything remains the same...

Comment: The example you provided for adding two values using curried function is way to simple to understand the concept of curried function, I am looking for some example that uses a complex relation and incorporates curriness in it, provide some help for the fibonacci series example I mentioned above It would be great :)

Comment: You can pretty easily change your function from type `(int * int) -> int seq` to type `int -> int -> int seq` by following the example. If this isn't what you want, which is easily possible, what do you want? I.e,. what type does the desired function have?

Comment: yes I want int -> int -> int seq , I am unable to do that , I am just not getting the thing right I know it is not that difficult it's just that I am stuck, could you please show me how it can be done with the same function as I did above