# Generating an infinite list of Fibonacci sequence in ML

Tags: sml, ml

I have to generate an infinite list containing a Fibonacci sequence. I am new to ML so I want to check if this is correct.

```
-datatype 'a infist=NIL
=           | CONS of 'a * (unit -> 'a inflist);
- fun fib a b = CONS (a , fn()=> fib b (a+b));
val fib=fn: int->int-int inflist
```

Is this what is called a generator function?
Will it give me an actual output i.e the infinite fib sequence when I give a and b inputs?

Comment: This quedtion has been asked at least twice in the last 48 hours. I [shared an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19747565/697630) a few hours ago in case you would like to consider it.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/q/19713850/697630

Answer (score 1):

Your datatype definition and your function definition seem correct. Although I still would have preferred a Fibonacci function that does not expect any arguments, to avoid the possibility of getting wrong input:

```
fun fibonacci () = 
   let
      fun fib(a,b) = Cons(a+b, fn() => fib(b,a+b))
   in
      Cons(0, fn()=> fib(0,1))
   end
```

This is what I would call [a stream](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5)

When you invoke it, it'll give an element of type infislist. You may consider writing some other functions to process your stream and interpret its contents. You may want see some examples of this in [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747565/697630), for example, functions like `takeWhile`, `take`, `filter`, `zip` and `toList`.

Comment: So what you have typed out is a generator function for an infinite seq of fib numbers?
Also is a generator something like a general purpose function that gives an output corresponding to any relevant input we give?

Comment: @user2948246 you can call it a generator function if you want. The structure being created is known as a stream. The function is simply a factory function that ends up creating a new infinite stream in this case.

Comment: Another doubt, The above code generates the following datatype

`
val fibonacci = fn : unit-> int inflist
`

How to get int->int inflist?

Comment: That skips a value. The inner function should be `fun fib(a,b) = Cons(b, fn() => fib(b,a+b))`